# Lombok not working on Eclipse Mars on Mac 10.11.3

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, lombok

I tried all the solutions given here on Stackoverflow regarding the same but it still won't work. Eclipse still shows compile errors on getter/setters. Steps i followed.

1. Download lombok.jar.
2. Open jar by double click and specify the location of eclipse.ini file as it was not accepting Eclipse.app.
3. Got confirmation popup that lombok has been installed in IDE.
4. Restarted/Open eclipse, the project still had compile errors for setters/getters.

My eclipse.ini file entries are as below:

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_91.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
-vmargs
........
..........
-javaagent:../Eclipse/lombok.jar
```

Location of eclipse file is as below:

```
/Users/vishal/jee-mars/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks!!

Comment: Try using an absolute path for the lombok jar, it is unlikely that the current directory is correct for `..` to work. Also note that there is no such release of Mac OS X as 10.11.13 - 10.11.6 was only released yesterday.

Comment: I had tried that too. Still same result. Regarding Mac OS its 10.11.3. My bad :). Corrected!

Comment: It's fixed. Actually i had created eclipse shortcut to launch eclipse (by copying Eclipse.app from installed location to the desktop). Later i installed Lombok and was still launching eclipse from the desktop shortcut. Just a while back i realised this and tried to launch eclipse from Eclipse.app from its actual location (/Users/vishal/jee-mars/) and did a project clean, everything worked fine. I have replaced the shortcut again, works fine. Thanks !!

Answer (score 10):

**Solution for Macbook:**

**Step 1** edit `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini with`

```
-Xbootclasspath/a:lombok.jar
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

just after

```
-vmargs
```

**Step 2** paste `lombok.jar` to `/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/`

**Step 3** After Eclipse restart:  `project > clean`

Comment: For my STS I had no eclipse.ini, but instead SpringToolSuite4.ini.  But this worked...

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of possible methods , Downloading lombak jar from https://projectlombok.org/ helped other than downloading from Maven .
and follow the above suggested installation methods .

Answer (score -1):

Execute on terminal

```
java -jar lombok.jar
```

After that, a window will open and you can follow the process to configure your lombok.

Comment: Incomplete answer. One needs to do a lot more and detailed explanation is lacking.

Comment: This is an incomplete answer. Given steps doesn't work for OSX or Mac OS

Comment: There's no specification about mac. @PandurangPatil try to read and apply if it works for you. It works very well in 2018.